# nfc_nci.default is not getting built in android

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to build the broadcom Nfc stack. The modules, libnfc_nci_jni, libnfc_nci are getting built. But the device and HAL specific implementations, nfc_nci.default is not getting built. The folder structure is

```
external 
  ├──libnfc_nci
     ├── halimpl --> nfc_nci.default
     |      ├── Android.mk --> contains 
     |      |                 'LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
     |      |                  include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH)) '
     |      ├── bcm2079x (contains makefile to make nfc_nci.default.so
     |
     ├── src --> libnfc_nci
     └── Android.mk -> build instructions for src 
                       + last line 'include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH)'
```

I donot know how to compile nfc_nci.default. Do I need to add the Nfc to PRODUCT_PACKAGES?
I am using mm to compile separately but that is not what I want to do. The emulator crashes with this separate compilation.

Code reference: [AndroidXRef](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/external/libnfc-nci/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changes did the job, thanks to Bluetooth module which gave me the direction!

1. Product Package name is Nfc. So, add `Nfc` alongside `Bluetooth` in JB_Source/build/target/product/mini.mk
2. change to `LOCAL_MODULE := nfc_nci.default` in JB_Source/external/libnfc-nci/halimpl/bcm2079x/Android.mk
3. Remove / disable make of nfc folders in JB_Source/hardware/libhardware/modules
4. Change to `LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES  := libnfc_nci_jni nfc_nci.default` in JB_Source/packages/apps/Nfc